# How to work with cloudkIt fetchOperation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, cloudkit

How do I access each property in cloudKit Users. I have an array of recordsIDs that I use to fetch. I get back the records (2 in this example) in one dictionary.

```
    NSMutableArray *recordIDs;
    for (NSString *recordName in recordNames) {
        CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:recordName];
        [recordIDs addObject:recordID];
    }
    CKFetchRecordsOperation *fetchOperation = [[CKFetchRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordIDs:recordIDs];
    fetchOperation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = ^(NSDictionary /* CKRecordID * -> CKRecord */ *recordsByRecordID, NSError *operationError) {

        NSLog(@"recordsByRecordID %@", recordsByRecordID);
};
```

Console logs the following:

```
2015-04-11 11:04:15.829 projectName[10154:555807] recordsByRecordID {
    "<CKRecordID: 0x7fea3bd86f80; _c835c6d554eafe23xxxxb65a1a9dd94d:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>" = "<CKRecord: 0x7fea44596fc0; recordType=Users, recordID=_c835c6d554eafe23xxxxb65a1a9dd94d:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=i7rxe5ce, values={\n    identifier = \"3E7837F6-C23C-44B2-89E8-5D9DF9AB061E\";\n    points = 50;\n    username = \"_c835c6d554eafe23xxxxb65a1a9dd94d\";\n}>";
    "<CKRecordID: 0x7fea3e0614d0; _cd5f8486186028eaxxx6b6597489619:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>" = "<CKRecord: 0x7fea3e2567a0; recordType=Users, recordID=_cd5f8486186028eaxxx6b6597489619:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=i7s7706j, values={\n    identifier = \"4B3B374E-42B0-47B7-8638-A8967C23FA21\";\n    points = 250;\n    username = \"_cd5f8486186028eaxxx6b6597489619\";\n}>";
}
```

I want to retrieve the username and points and add it to a local dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Looks like I need to pass in the recordID for each record then the key to retrieve.

```
for (CKRecordID *recordID in recordsByRecordID) {
    NSString *pointsString  = recordsByRecordID[recordID][PointsKey];
    NSLog(@"string %@", pointsString);
}
```